# SQL Select right of a "&" mark

Tags: sql, string, select

I am writing some sql code that needs to select a specific number of characters in a string. An example string would be "3350775&1.3.". I need to split a column up into two columns, one are the numbers on the left hand side of the & and the other is the right. The left hand side is easy because it is always 7 digits in length so i can use

```
SELECT 
Left(Col, 7) as 'Order Number'
From tableA where Col like ('%&%')
```

However, the numbers on the right hand side can change in length. It could be 1.1., or 12.3. or a variety of different combinations. Is there a way to select the & and then select all the numbers on the right hand side of it. Some examples would be as follows:

3154878&1.1. would be 3154878 in col1 and 1.1. in col2

3154878&12.1. would be 3154878 in col1 and 12.1. in col2.

Comment: What is your RDBMS (SQL Flavor)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, I think this should work for you:-

```
SELECT 
Left(Col, 7) as 'Order Number',
Replace(Col, Left(Col, 7)+'&','') as 'Right hand side'
From tableA where Col like ('%&%')
```

Another possible (simpler perhaps) solution would be to use stuff to replace the first 8 characters with an empty string:-

```
SELECT 
Left(Col, 7) as 'Order Number',
STUFF(Col, 1, 8, '') as 'Right hand side'
From tableA where Col like ('%&%')
```

This is one of those problems that can take various solutions that all return the same result.

Comment: will check in 10 mins.

Comment: I looked into the replace function and I want to make sure I am understanding this code correctly. For the replace statement are you just inverting the selection, as in, are you selecting the first 7 digits plus the & and then just selecting whats left over?

Comment: More or less, yes.  The replace function essentially replaces the first 8 characters of the statement with an empty string.

Comment: ahhh, now the '' makes sense. Thanks for that knowledge bomb. Will use in the future.